# What global attributes does the amp-video tag support in amp-story?

Tags: video, amp-html, amp-story

**reference**
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

The `<video>` tag also supports the Global Attributes in HTML.  Does amp-video in amp-story support the Global Attributes in HTML?

**Global Attributes**

- accesskey    Specifies a shortcut key to activate/focus an element
- class    Specifies one or more classnames for an element (refers to a class in a style sheet)
- contenteditable  Specifies whether the content of an element is editable or not
- data-*   Used to store custom data private to the page or application
- dir  Specifies the text direction for the content in an element
- draggable    Specifies whether an element is draggable or not
- dropzone     Specifies whether the dragged data is copied, moved, or linked, when dropped
- hidden   Specifies that an element is not yet, or is no longer, relevant
- id   Specifies a unique id for an element
- lang     Specifies the language of the element's content
- spellcheck   Specifies whether the element is to have its spelling and grammar checked or not
- style    Specifies an inline CSS style for an element
- tabindex     Specifies the tabbing order of an element
- title    Specifies extra information about an element
- translate    Specifies whether the content of an element should be translated or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the supported attributes (of the ones you've listed) that are expected to be used (i.e. listed in various parts of the `amp-story` documentation or GitHub repo) are:

- class
- dir
- id
- lang

Several others may work, but might break since they adding a different interaction model than AMP stories.